# App.config in executable so I can edit it later? VB.net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

So I have one problem...
I decided to build my solution in EXECUTABLE and in my project i have included app.config file which contains connection strings to database...

```
> <configuration>
>     <configSections>
>     </configSections>
>     <connectionStrings>
>         <add name="VitabaseVB.My.MySettings.VITABASEConnectionString"
>             connectionString="server=.\;database=VITABASE;trusted_connection=True"
>             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
>     </connectionStrings>  </configuration>
```

and my problem is that when i make Executable i got this

[image: exe file]

and in app files this
[image: app folder here]
when I open my config deploy i see code provided earlier with config string.
My problem Is when I edit that in another machine running SQLSERVER and type

```
connectionString="server=.\;database=VITABASE;trusted_connection=True"
```

replacing dot with name of server and installing application.... app cannot connect to server... and there is no password and nothing on server...

2nd problem is configuring sql server to be avaliable over network so I can Install my app on three other machines running network sql remote server...
Never done that earlier so if anyone could help It would be appriciated...
I found many tutorials how to configure sql connection remotely but in a sea of tuts cannot determine what is the best solution... may of them are telling you to hardcode the IP ADRESS of server but what if that IP ADRESS is dynamical???

Comment: if you do not have the sql server instance name then provide connetionstring without slash example : `connectionString="server=servername;database=VITABASE;trusted_connection=True`

Comment: good that makes sense but i entered in another problem now ... i compiled database cleand it and made deploy and lost config.deploy file??? and now cannot get it back into rebuilded app?

Comment: did you again rebuild your app?

Comment: Yes I rebuild it...hmmm not sure what is going on... but ok no problem... still I need answer for second step

Comment: Okay now tell me where you are stuck? did you try changing the servername without slash in `connection string`?

Comment: i managed to get connection... and connection is working on local computer... but as multiuser app I need that app to be able to connect from other computer. I set up remote connection on my server accessed it from another computer over SSMS and sa user and password, but when I define that password in connection string i get error login failed for Guest user. my conn string:
            connectionString="server=192.168.1.75\SQLEXPRESS;database=VITABASE;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;user id = sa;password = Vitabase123;trusted_connection=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: remove this `trusted_connection=True` attribute from your connection string and then try it works.

Comment: @ Sudhakar Tillapudi - sorry I didn't answer sooner but have been too busy with PL programming, I will try it later today then I will notify you if it worked... thx for everything

Comment: @ Sudhakar Tillapudi Removing trusted_connection = true from my connection string worked!!! THANK YOU BIG TIME!

Comment: You are welcome :) I'm glad to be help of you.